# default value for dropdown collection day of birth field in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

- rails 3.2.8
- simpleform

Im trying to get a default value for each of the day, month, year fields a "Select from list" while keep the below code with styling. Tried nummerous attempts, anyone knows how to do this? Would be very much appreciated thx!

```
= p.label t(:date_of_birth)
      = p.input :dob,
                :class => "extra",
                :as => :date,   :start_year => Date.today.year,
                                :end_year => Date.today.year - 80,
                                :month => Date.today.month,
                                :order => [:day, :month, :year],
                                :label => false,
                                :input_html => { :style => "width: 102px" }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ugh.. I found out myself after 30 minutes more digging, it was just a simple :prompt => "select" to assign to all 3 dropdowns of the dob collection.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is `:include_blank => "Select from list"`